# Vsftpd. 553 ошибка при работе с ftp

Tags: debian, ftp, vsftpd

Настроил на сервере ftp с помощью vsftpd. Конфиг следующий:

```html
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
idle_session_timeout=600
data_connection_timeout=60
ftpd_banner=###FTP###
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
max_clients=20
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Права на папку есть у локального пользователя, от которого присоединяюсь к ftp

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 maxftp maxftp 4.0K Mar 24 22:14 ftp
```

Коннект проходит

```html
ftp <myip>
Connected to <myip>
220 Welcome to ftpd!
Name (): maxftp
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Однако, при попытке записать файл получаю ошибку или таймаут

```
ftp> put Downloads/about 
local: Downloads/about remote: Downloads/about
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
```

так получаю таймаут

```
curl -T Downloads/about ftp://<myip> --user <myuser>
```

что не учитываю или где допускаю ошибку?

Comment: Заметил, что допустил ошибку в синтаксисе put. нужно put Downloads/about  test. Файл копируется в каталог ftp с именем test успешно, однако я не могу его удалить. И так же, как и раньше, не могу организовать трансфер c помощью curl или filezilla. Может кто-то сможет поделиться своим конфигом?

Answer (score 0):

Данный конфиг подходит для настройки FTP-сервера, который не находится за фаерволом. Однако, в моем случае проблема оказалась в следующем.

По умолчанию в vsftpd включена опция пассивного режима

```
pasv_enable=YES
```

и сервер для передачи файлов использует порт от 1024 и выше (см. теорию по различию пассивного и активного режима работы ftp).

А так как файрвол разрешает для прохода только трафик 20, 21 портов (настроил заранее), получается, что передача файлов невозможна.

Изменяем опцию в конфиге и перезагружаем сервер

```
pasv_enable=NO
```

Отключив пассивный режим работы, мы работаем в активном режиме (20 порт для передачи файлов) и все успешно передается